# If $X$ is a maximum linearly independent subset of $V$, then $X$ is basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

> Let be a field $F$ and $V$ a vector space over $F$. Prove that if $X$
> is a maximum linearly independent subset of $V$, then $X$ is basis of
> $V$

**My proof**

Suppose that $X$ **is not** a basis of $V$. That implies either

- $X$ is not linearly independent
  \begin{align}
  \Longrightarrow X \text{ is not a maximum linearly independent subset of } V
  \end{align}
- Or $X$ does not generates $V$.
  \begin{align}
  &\Longrightarrow \exists \text{ a basis } S \text{ of } V \text{ such that } X \subset S\\
  &\text{But } S \text{ is linearly independent since it's a basis}\\
  &\Longrightarrow X \text{ is not a maximum linearly independent subset of } V
   \end{align}

Therefore, if $X$ is a basis of $V$ $\Longrightarrow$ $X$ is a maximum linearly independent subset of $V$.

**My doubt:** I know there are several other ways to prove this, but my way is correct? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The first case can't happen by hypothesis.

Comment: Your proof seems to rely upon the theorem that "every linearly independent set of vectors is the subset of some basis". Is that a theorem that you have at your disposal, or would you need to prove that in order to use it? That theorem seems rather equivalent to the one that you are trying to prove: maximal meaning "not a proper subset" of some basis.

Comment: @Joe I guess that I would have to prove it

Comment: Either $X$ spans $V$ or it doesn't.  If it does span $V$, then, since $X$ is linearly independent, it is a basis for $V$.  If $X$ does not span $V$, then it can't be maximal, because there must exist some element of $V$ that is outside the span of $X$.

Comment: Does the problem statement say "maximum" or "maximal"?  (I think "maximum" is typically incorrect except in the trivial case $V$ has only two elements)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you used what you tried to prove. Assume for a contradiction that it does not generate $V$. Then there is a $u\in V\setminus X$ s.t $u$ can not be generated by a final sum $\sum_{i=1}^n c_nu_n$ where $u_1,...,u_n\in X$. Now look at $X\cup\{u\}$, Since $u$ is not a linear combination of elements of $X$, you should be able to show that $X\subsetneq X\cup \{u\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X$ is not a basis of $V$. Since $X$ is linearly independent, this means $X$ does not span $V$. Pick $v \in V \setminus \text{span}(X)$. It is easy to show that $X \cup \{v\}$ is a linearly independent set, contradicting that $X$ is a maximal linearly independent set.